# using ng-repeat and indexing for textbox input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to use the ng-repeat and indexing for a question/answer scenario in angularjs and mvc. So for my database, I have two tables:

1. Question

   - Question
   - InputType (textbox, checkbox, radio ect.)
2. Answers

   - Answer

There is a one to many relationship between the question and answer table because for one question there can be many answers from many different people. In my angularjs, I am using $scope variables and get methods to get the questions from the database, using an ng-repeat to repeat the questions in a div. This is done like so:

```
//Question

 $scope.Question_NetSuite = {
   Question1: '',
   input_type: ''
 }

//Answer:
$scope.SysIntClient =
  {
    SysInt_ID: '',
    ID: '',
    Answer: ''
  }

$http.get('/Home/getUserInfo')
  .then(function (response) {
    $scope.Question_NetSuite = response.data;
    console.log("status:" + response.status);
    console.log("data: " + $scope.Question_NetSuite);
  })
```

My div and html looks as follows:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="(index, question) in Question_NetSuite">
  Value: {{question.Question1}} 
  {{ index }}
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <label class="labelQuestion" id="question_label" for="question_answer">
      {{question.Question1}}
    </label>
  </div>
  //This seems to be where I am struggling
  <input type="text" ng-model="SysIntClient.Answer" />
  Value: {{SysIntClient.Answer}}
</div>
```

The problem I am having is that I want to link an answer input from the text box to the question that I am getting from the database. I am new to angularjs and mvc, so I know I need to use a repeater and I need to assign the answer to the same index as the question. I just don't know how to do it.

How would you suggest I link the question to the answer?

Comment: Is there any ID that would assign answer to a question?

Comment: There is. I included a QuestionID in my question db that links to the answer table as a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Using index is a bad idea. Your need to pass question ID inside your questions array and question ID for each answer object. Something like this:

```
$scope.questionsList = [
   {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "My first question"
   },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "My second question"
   }
]


$scope.answersList = {
  "1": [   // question ID
    {
       "id": 1,
       "answer": "First answer for question id 1"
    },
    {
       "id": 2,
       "answer": "Second answer for question id 1"
    }
  ],
  "2": [  // question ID
    {
       "id": 1,
       "answer": "First answer for question id 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Repeat over questionsList and then through answersList for current question.id:

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questionsList">
  [{{question.id}}]: {{question.name}}
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="answer in answersList[question.id]">
      [{{answer.id}}]: {{answer.answer}}
    </li>     
  </ul>      
</div>
```

Here's a working plunkr: http://jsfiddle.net/0pafvrhu/

Comment: Could this work the same way if the `li` was a textbox instead? could I still map the answer the same way?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse.
`<li ng-repeat="answer in answersList[question.id]">
      <input type="text" ng-model="answer" />
    </li>`

Comment: My only concern with this is that the questions are pre-set in the database, so populating the array of questions is easy. it's the mapping of the answers (that I need to get from the user and not an array) that concerns me